# Why does solr-node query gives a wrong document version number?

Tags: solr, version, document

I am using Solr 7.6. While performing a search query, Solr gives a wrong *version* field of a document but all the other fields are correct.

In Solr dashboard the query gives the following result:

```
{
        "id":"518fce46-3617-4380-aaf6-8f6d36e08e6a",
        "type":"tag",
        "count":1,
        "_version_":1626999925241806848
}
```

Whereas, solr-node search function gives:

```
{
         "id": "518fce46-3617-4380-aaf6-8f6d36e08e6a",
         "type": "tag",
         "count": 1,
         "_version_": 1626999925241806800
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial guess is that the solr-node module returns the value as a double (instead of as a string), and the precision of a double isn't good enough to represent the value `1626999925241806848` exactly.

We can confirm this directly in our browser's console:

```
-> 1626999925241806848
<- 1626999925241806800
```

i.e. if we input the numeric value `1626999925241806848`, it'll be represented by the floating point number that's closest, and that's `1626999925241806800`.

solr-node should probably return these values as a string when they exceed the representable value for ints.

**Update**: solr-node [details this at their overview page](http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/):

> Use json-bigint to handle correctly numbers too large for Javascript Number such as the values of the fields *l and _version. By default json-bigint library is not used because the performance difference compared to the native JSON library is too important with "large" chunk of JSON (https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client/issues/114#issuecomment-54165595), but you want to enable it if you use the Optimistic Concurreny feature available in Solr 4.x, along with RealTime Get and Atomic Updates features because they use the *version* field. In order to enable it do `var client = solr.createClient({ bigint : true})` or directly on the client instance `client.options.bigint = true`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: If you need the version field to be returned correctly, you can use the bigint json library as referenced on the solr-node page. I've updated my answer with the relevant information from that page. Be aware that you might not need the version field to be correct, unless you're using functionality that depends on it.